# Repeat data issues SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, inner-join

Had a quick browse to see if any previous questions related to my issue, couldn't see any.

Basically I'm doing this database for my online Cert IV course and if I weren't completely stuck (as I have been for the past few months) I wouldn't be asking for major help on this

I've got an Antiques database that is supposed to show the Customer Name, Sales Date, Product Name and Sales Price and only list the items that were sold between 2 dates and order them by said dates. Nothing I do results in not having repeat data

I've got 4 tables for this particular query Customers, Sales and Products, Tables are set up like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Customers](
[CustID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[firstName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[lastName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Customers] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Sales](
[SalesNo] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[CustID] [int] NOT NULL,
[salesDate] [date] NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Sales] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Products](
[ProductID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[prodName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[prodYear] [int] NOT NULL,
[prodType] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[salesPrice] [money] NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Products] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ProductSales](
[ProductID] [int] NOT NULL,
[SalesNo] [int] NOT NULL
```

My query looks like this

```
SELECT (Customers.firstName + ' ' + Customers.lastName) AS Customers_Name,
    Sales.salesDate, Products.prodName, Sales.salesPrice
FROM Customers, ProductSales JOIN Products ON ProductSales.ProductID = Products.ProductID
                             JOIN Sales ON ProductSales.SalesNo = Sales.SalesNo
WHERE Sales.salesDate BETWEEN '2016-06-03' AND '2016-06-06'
ORDER BY Sales.salesDate
```

This is what shows up when I run this query:

[image: Queried Data]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This does not look like MySQL problem. Are you sure that you are not using SQL Server instead.

Comment: DON'T mix implicit and explicit joins DO add sample data as text to the question.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya You're right, I've corrected the mistake in the title. Thanks

Comment: @P.Salmon an answer has already been provided which works but for anyone coming to this in the future I'll add sample data. Thanks

Comment: @user3618687 believe it or not this is a very frequent question on this site.

Comment: @P.Salmon Maybe the search terms I used didn't provide any of those results. I always do try to find previous questions to what I am looking for, but sometimes I just can't seem to find them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below - you need to join customer table properly

```
SELECT (Customers.firstName + ' ' + Customers.lastName) AS Customers_Name,
    Sales.salesDate, Products.prodName, Sales.salesPrice
FROM ProductSales JOIN Products ON ProductSales.ProductID = Products.ProductID
                             JOIN Sales ON ProductSales.SalesNo = Sales.SalesNo
JOIN Customers on  Sales.[CustID]=Customers.[CustID]
WHERE Sales.salesDate BETWEEN '2016-06-03' AND '2016-06-06'
ORDER BY Sales.salesDate
```

Comment: So I needed to join Customers through the Sales table instead of on it's own? It makes sense, that way it's filtered information instead of just the entire table

Comment: @user3618687, yes you need to define relation between customer and sales table properly, in your query u didn't define the relationship

Comment: Thanks, as you can tell I am not as versed in SQL as I would like to be. the whole joins and stuff get me a little confused but thank you so much for the help.